# ACL permissions not inherited

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions, ubuntu-14.04, access-control-list

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server with an EXT4 partition. I want to change what permissions new files and folders get when they are created in `/home/myuser`. I set some options with `setfacl`, and `getfacl /home/myuser` returns the following

```
# file: home/myuser/
# owner: myuser
# group: myuser
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
```

Now, in `/home/myuser/`, I run `touch test.txt`. `getfacl test.txt` returns

```
# file: test.txt
# owner: myuser
# group: myuser
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::r--
```

If I run `mkdir testfolder && getfacl testfolder/`, I get

```
# file: testfolder/
# owner: myuser
# group: myuser
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
```

I tried `setfacl -dm g:myuser:rwx /home/myuser`, after which `touch test.txt && getfacl test.txt` returns

```
# file: test.txt
# owner: myuser
# group: myuser
user::rw-
group::rwx               #effective:rw-
group:myuser:rwx         #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

Why? I want all files and folders inside `/home/myuser` to have 770 mode.

Answer (score 2):

Add default ACLs, like this:

```
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::---
```

Default ACLs are applied on new files and directories under the affected directory.

You can use the following command to accomplish this:

```
setfacl -dm u::rwx,g::rwx,m::rwx,o::0 /home/myuser
```

Comment: Now directories have the right permissions. However, files are 660. http://pastebin.com/xu0E81jf I tested it with /home/myuser/test directory, because I didn't want to mess up my home folder.

Comment: I'm not sure why that happens, but I've always seen that as a feature. I think it's better to explicitly enable the execute flag on files than having it set always, just in case.

Comment: Yes, it might be better to enable it on per file basis but it should still work. Running `setfacl -m u::rwx,g::rwx,m::rwx,o::0 testfile` works as it should.